# Why we need to define 8 topologies in von Neumann algebra??

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It is true that strong operator topology is defined to make sense pointwise limit in von Neumann algebra and weak operator topology is defined for getting compactness on unit ball, ultraweak topology is defined to get compatibility in predual, why are the either 5 topologies defined to get more information about the algebra? Can I have more general clarity on these?

Comment: I think this question will be easier to answer if you listed the eight topologies you are referring to.

Comment: According to Takesaki volume 1, they are (i)$\sigma$ -strong*, (ii)$\sigma$-strong, (iii)$\sigma$-weak,(iv)strong*,(v)strong,(vi)weak,(vii)uniform/norm topologies